# Restrict Video as per content rating in tvOS

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, tvos, apple-tv

Restriction is enabled from setting  of Apple TV and content rating for show and movie is being set.

How to display parental pin screen when viewing restricted video?

I am using default AVPlayerController for viewing video.